# Android Devices reported as iPhone in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have had Google Analytics (Universal Analytics) configured for several days and collected a lot of information.  I have tested the site using a variety of browsers across a range of devices, on both desktop and mobile.

However, when I drill down into **Audience > Mobile > Devices** the only Mobile listed is **Apple iPhone**. This is despite testing the site with a variety of both Apple and Android based devices.

The user agent string would appear to be sent correctly by the devices; here is one Android example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; en-nz; SAMSUNG GT-I9505 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

I have spent a LOT of time "Googling" this problem, but cannot find anything that resolves it.

*I was under the impression that this sort of tracking should be enabled out of the box - or is there something else I need to set up?*

Comment: This sounds weird as it should be reported correctly like you write, "out of the box". Do you have any filters maybe that ignores traffic from your own IP-adress and accessing it through WiFi? 

Have you tried looking at the exact traffic using campaign parameters to identify the exact visit? www.domain.com?utm_campaign=test etc. Have you given GA enough time to process the data before looking at it?

Comment: No filters and GA been setup for a couple of weeks, so plenty of time to process? It only, needs 48 hours max, right? It was processing the iPhone no problems and was recording data for Android devices, just not listing the device type. That said, this morning I magically started getting android devices reported...

Comment: Hmm... strange. But does it look like it has been corrected?

Comment: I don't know why but this just started working a week or so later. Nothing changed regarding the GA setup. Very frustrating to not know why.

Comment: Might have been an error in processing on Googles side then? Sounds odd though... Haven't read about any bug reports around that period. Glad it fixed itself though :)

Comment: I have the same issue. Android is under-reported. It is impossible that 85% of phones worldwide do not trump iOS in the analytics.